# CSS how to fill height of container?

Tags: css

I have a container and two div inside it:

[image]

The container has a fixed 500px height.
I don't know head's size, but I want to fill all the container height with body.
I tried to set this height value to body:

- **100%**: doesn't work, because the body get height of 500px from its parent (container) and overflow.
- **auto**: body may be empty or only with some short content and in this case the body height will be lower than free container space.

How to fill the container with a fitting body?

This is the fiddle with the example:

```
#body{ height 100%; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s2ems5hm/1/

Comment: Do you already have any code?

Comment: both head and body height values unknown?

Comment: If your body is child of container tag, then height=100% should work. If not then you can go with JavaScript/jQuery

Comment: Yes, it depends on content...

Comment: I add the fiddle, as you can see the height 100% doesn't work because it overflow the container due to head height.

Comment: @Tobia something [like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/3eLvneh7/)

Comment: Yes! this is the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with `display: table/table-row`:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
}

.container{
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.head, .body{
    display: table-row;
}

.head{
    background-color: blue;
}

.body{
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="head">some head</div>
    <div class="body">foobar</<div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3eLvneh7/)

Also, I used [box-sizing: border-box](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).

Answer (score 4):

This is what [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) was made for:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.header {
  background-color: lightblue;  
}

.body {
  flex: 1;  
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header<br>unknown<br>height</div>
  <div class="body"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I love flexbox but still there is a [browser compability](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) issue regarding "old" IE versions.

Comment: @Vucko I am trying to make the internet a better place by not supporting those old versions and forcing the user to update ;) (yeah, I know, not possible in many environments...)

Comment: @Vucko Old IE's (without flexbox) represent only 2.23% of global use. The rest uses browser who do support flexbox. You do the math...